# Elasticsearch - how to bulk insert index + add index to alias?

Tags: elasticsearch, alias

I have a script that creates indices which are generated periodically using the _bulk API. For example, it would create the following:

```
/foo_2017-06-01/bar/abcd
/foo_2017-05-31/bar/efgh
....
```

But I want an alias to, basically, index all of these indices - and newer ones. For example I want:

```
/foo --> [/foo_2017-06-01, /foo_2017-05-31, ...]
```

Is this possible? Or what can I do to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Templates to do this:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/indices-templates.html

Templates allow you to apply settings to newly created indexes automatically. For example, the following template will apply to all indexes with the 'foo_' prefix and add it to the foo alias.

```
PUT _template/template_1
{
    "template" : "foo_*",
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1
    },
    "aliases" : {,
        "foo" : {} 
    }
}
```